# matrix transformation - eigenvector

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

I am trying to understand eigenvectors.
An Eigenvector is nothing more than a vector that points to some place. This pointing vector will then be invariant under linear transformations.

Now my questions:

- Ok so this vector is invariant. So what? (in my case for attitude determination algorithm I even less understand what this could give me as useful information)
- how does a simple $4\times 4$ matrix actually represent a transformation?

Comment: You multiply a $4$ dimensional vector by the $4\times4$ matrix on the left and you get another $4$-d vector.  That is how the matrix gives a transformation of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant in my case there is not even a multiplication. I just construct a 4x4 matrix and calculate the eigenvector and eigenvalue from it...

Comment: Imagine a transformation in two dimensions.  The matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc}3&0\\0&5\end{array}\right]$ has two eigenvectors because the transformation stretches by $3$ in the $x$-direction and by $5$ in the $y$-direction. But the matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right]$ has no (real) eigenvectors because it is a rotation, it doesn't stretch (or shrink) in any direction, all directions are changed.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, ow ok! so a matrix actually always represents "a stretch" in some dimension(s). Ok now I understand better. I do understand what an eigenvector is. But in which way is it interesting to know where the eigenvector points or that it is invariant? (especially for attitude determination, I don't see why/how this information would be useful)

Comment: It's just a way of dissecting a transformation to understand it better.  Ones that merely stretch and shrink in several directions are some of the simpler transformations, so when they are like that we usually can analyze them better.   For example every transformation in two dimensions is a combination of stretching, shrinking, rotating and reflecting.

Comment: so an eigenvector tells me how a matrix transforms (=shrinks, stretches, rotates and, reflects) a vector  ?

Comment: Actually an eigenvector just tells you directions that the matrix shrinks or stretches, or reflects, it doesn't tell you about rotations.  If a matrix gives a rotation (in two dimensions) then it actually has no eigenvectors at all.

Comment: and now 'the' question: "why do you want to know that?" You already have the matrix, why do you need another vector describing this matrix? (I can't understand why it is used in attitude determination)

Comment: If a $4\times4$ matrix (for example) has four eigenvectors, then that tells you a lot about the transformation, it tells you that if you choose the right coordinates of the vector space that the matrix takes on a particularly simple form, all zeros except on the diagonal.  That characterization of a transformation is very simple and as such can be very convenient and useful.  But to answer your question better we would need a specific example of where these notions are being used.

Comment: specific example: page 4-14 q-method http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~cdhall/courses/aoe4140/attde.pdf

Comment: They are are looking for a stationary value of $g'(\overline{\bf q})$ and they show (4.71) that $\overline{\bf q}$ is actually an eigenvector.  Thus they can use the standard methods of finding eigenvectors to find $\overline{\bf q}$.

Comment: wooow ok now this clarifies everything, thank you so much!! So actually in my case the eigenvector (altough it equals the final result) doesn't mean anything, we just use this method to find q? In this case it doesn't have anything to do with transformation, etc... ?

Comment: Well a matrix can always be interpreted as a transformation, so you can't say it doesn't have anything to do with transformations.  But you don't have to think of it as a transformation, it's not important to the solution, all you need to know is $\overline{\bf q}$ is an eigenvector of the matrix to solve for it using standard methods.

Answer (score 1):

> An Eigenvector is nothing more than a vector that points to some place

No, an eigenvector is a vector that points to the same place after being transformed by the matrix.

---

As far as usefulness of eigenvectors go, it is very hard to find a mathematical concept that has more real life applications then the concept of eigenvectors:
for example, the PageRank algorithm, which finds the dominant *eigenvector* of a matrix, is one of the most important parts in Google's algorithms for ranking webpages. Other examples include:

- Quantum mechanics
- Image recognition
- Calculating frequencies of musical instruments
- "Principal component analysis" in statistics

And many more. Each of these fields has it's own problems, but all of these problems can be translated into finding an eigenvector for a specific matrix. The "meaning" behind these vectors is then bestowed upon the solutions not by algebra ("pointing in the same direction"), but by the field that first had the problem!

Comment: But what do the values inside an eigenvector express? just the information about how the vector is "placed/oriented" in space? I really cannot understand why we need to know this! (especially for attitude determination)

Comment: @JaqcuesMartin As I said, the values represent whatever the particular scientific field needs them to represent.